# How to customize LogFormat for Apache Virtual Hosts?

Tags: apache-http-server, logging, logfiles

I really need some help with this. My server has multiple virtual hosts, each virtual host has its access log, I need to be able to customize the LogFormat for each virtual host exist on server. I have modified LogFormat in `httpd.conf` but it actually affects only the master access log and not the virtual hosts.

Here is my LogFormat:

```
<IfModule log_config_module>
LogFormat "%v:%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %{CF-Connecting-IP}i" combinedvhost
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %{CF-Connecting-IP}i" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %{CF-Connecting-IP}i" common

CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
CustomLog logs/access_log combinedvhost

<IfModule logio_module>
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %{CF-Connecting-IP}i" combinedio
</IfModule>

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_log_config.c>
LogFormat "%v:%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %{CF-Connecting-IP}i" combinedvhost
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %{CF-Connecting-IP}i" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %{CF-Connecting-IP}i" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

CustomLog logs/access_log common
CustomLog logs/access_log combined
CustomLog logs/access_log combinedvhost

</IfModule>
```

The above LogFormat only affects the master access log which located at: `/usr/local/apache/logs/access_log` However, it does not affect any of the virtual hosts on server that have their access logs located at: `/home/username/access-logs/domain.com`

I'm not sure if I have something wrong in the LogFormat itself or I'm missing something. I've spent many hours trying to solve this problem but didn't find a solution. I'd greatly appreciate it if someone could shed some light on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to add CustomLog directives inside each VirtualHost in your Apache config files. For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.site1.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/www.site1.com/htdocs
  CustomLog /var/log/apache/www.site1.com-access.log combined
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache/www.site1.com-error.log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.site2.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/www.site2.com/htdocs
  CustomLog /var/log/apache/www.site2.com-access.log combined
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache/www.site2.com-error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

There are more useful examples [here](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ExampleVhosts).

Comment: Can you elaborate on that (how to do it)?

Answer (score 0):

Trick is that you should have both LogFormat and CustomLog in same VirtualHost pool

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName my.site.com
    LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %D  " commonvhost
    ErrorLog "|/opt/mw/apache-2.4.25-instance1/bin/rotatelogs /apps/logs/my.site.com-443-error.%Y.%m.%d.log 86400"
    CustomLog "|/opt/mw/apache-2.4.25-instance1/bin/rotatelogs /apps/logs/my.site.com-443-access.%Y.%m.%d.log 86400" commonvhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my.site.com
    LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %D  " commonvhost
    ErrorLog "|/opt/mw/apache-2.4.25-instance1/bin/rotatelogs /apps/logs/my.site.com-80-error.%Y.%m.%d.log 86400"
    CustomLog "|/opt/mw/apache-2.4.25-instance1/bin/rotatelogs /apps/logs/my.site.com-80-access.%Y.%m.%d.log 86400" commonvhost
</VirtualHost>
```